# Multiplying String in a list, Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am trying to multiply strings in a list. For instance, when I have a list like `["hello","World"]` and I want to 'multiply' it by 2, I want to end up with `["hello","hello","World","World"]`.

Here's what I came up with:

```
rep :: Int -> [String] -> [String]
rep n [] = []
rep n [x:xs] = replicate n [x] ++ rep n [xs]
```

But it gives me exception:

> (298,1)-(299,44): Non-exhaustive patterns in function rep

I am totally new to this language and I do not have any ideas how to sort this out. Can you help?

Comment: `[x:xs]` is not the pattern for a list with at least one element, it is `(x:xs)`.

Comment: furthermore you will need to call `replicate n x` and `rep n xs`.

Comment: I would suggest using `map` to apply your replication. Then you need only flatten the resulting nested list. `rep n xs = concat $ map (replicate n) xs`

Comment: @Rainbacon You can leave off `xs` and use `concatMap`, so: `rep n = concatMap (replicate n)`

Comment: You can use `rep n = (>>= replicate n)`

Comment: Or even shorter: `rep = (=<<) . replicate`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I find that `rep = concatMap . replicate` has a nice balance between readability and conciseness, but of course your solutions work too.

Comment: @MichaelKohl: yeah, I agree :). It is more that I am always supprised how expressive Haskell is. But you are definitely correct :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your fist problem is that the pattern for non-empty lists is wrong, it should be `(x:xs)`, not `[x:xs]`.
- Furthermore, [replicate](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:replicate) expects a single element and turns it into a list of length `n`, so it should be `replicate n x`, not `replicate n [x]`.
- In a similar vain `xs` is already a list.

If you fix all of this you'll end up with the following, which actually works as intended:

```
rep :: Int -> [String] -> [String]
rep n [] = []
rep n (x:xs) = replicate n x ++ rep n xs
```

That said there are many different ways one could write this, for example with [concatMap](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=concatMap):

```
rep n = concatMap (replicate n)
```

or

```
rep = concatMap . replicate
```