# In Haskell how can you multiply a list of string?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write a function that takes a list of Strings and an Int and returns that list of strings in which every string is "int" times. That is:

```
duplicate :: [String] -> Int -> [String]
duplicate ["ab","ac","yt","hfg","lkj","poi"] 2
```

the output should be

```
["ab","ab","ac","ac","yt","yt","hfg","hfg","lkj","lkj","poi","poi"]
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the expected output? I would expect that to be expected for `duplicate ["ab","ac","yt","hfg","lkj","poi"] 2`. Also, please add the code you have so far.

Comment: That's not a question.

Comment: yes sorry it is 2 not 3. sorry

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiplying String in a list, Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47353797/multiplying-string-in-a-list-haskell)

Answer (score 1):

```
duplicate = (. replicate) . (>>=)
```

or more basic

```
duplicate xs n = concatMap (replicate n) xs
```

if you want to have list multiplication by notation as well

```
> let (**) :: [a] -> Int -> [a]
|     (**) = (. replicate) . (>>=)

> ["a","b"]**3
["a","a","a","b","b","b"]
```