# how can i write a function which will multiply every alphabet of string n times in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write a function that takes a String and an Int and returns that every element of string  is multiplyed "int" times. That is:

```
duplicate :: String -> Int -> String
duplicate " abc " 2
```

the output should be

```
Main >> "   aabbcc   "
```

Comment: `duplicate = flip (concatMap . replicate)`

Comment: [You asked the same question 3hrs ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47356188/in-haskell-how-can-you-multiply-a-list-of-string). You have made no improvement. This is spam.

Comment: @AJFarmar It's not spam, it's a duplicate. The system has automatic penalties for repeatedly asking poor questions.

Comment: @4castle This question is an almost perfect duplicate of the one linked, and by the same user.

Comment: @AJFarmar It's a bad question, and a duplicate, and deserves to be downvoted and closed. But that's a separate question from whether it is spam: it is not trying to sell us Nigerian-prince pills or something.

Answer (score 2):

You should look at the following functions in Prelude:

- `map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]` to "do someting" with every element of a list
- `replicate :: Int -> a -> [a]` to replicate an item n times
- `concat :: Foldable t => t [a] -> [a]` to concat, e.g a list of lists into a single list

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are many ways to achieve what you want:

You could either do it recursively...

```
duplicate :: String -> Int -> String
duplicate (c:s) n 
    | s == [] = replicate n c
    | otherwise = replicate n c ++ duplicate s n
```

... or as the others pointed out, by using some of the Prelude functions ...

```
duplicate' :: String -> Int -> String
duplicate' s n = concatMap (replicate n) s
```

... or by using fold ...

```
duplicate'' :: String -> Int -> String
duplicate'' s n = foldr1 (\c acc -> replicate n c ++ acc) "" s
```

You would use these functions like:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do 
    print $ duplicate   "abc" 3 -- "aaabbbccc"
    print $ duplicate'  "abc" 3 -- "aaabbbccc"
    print $ duplicate'' "abc" 3 -- "aaabbbccc"
```